# Can we programmatically determine the components of a website by crawling its content?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, web-crawler, analysis

Can we programmatically determine the components of a website by crawling its content?

I understand that this seems kind-of impossible but i think anything is possible in code. I am trying brainstorm ideas based on which i could determine the individual components of a website if i have crawled all of its data!

I am interested in determining components such as , for example , in case of a ecommerce website, i would want to determine or identify:
1. Login Url
2. Registration Url
3. Dashboard url
4. Add order url
5. Shopping cart url
6. Logout Url
and more

The information we might have can be:
1. Session, Cookies, Metadata, 
2. Backlinks (internal and external)
3. Forms in a page, fields in a page etc

Any ideas or pointers will be greatly helpful.

Comment: perhaps recursively follow all `<a>` tags in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the raw HTML results by crawling the domain. And to your URL getting question: Yes, you can determine login, register etc. URL's according to URL and the HTML elements by a system, which can be designed with some experiments.

Worked on crawling gifts' pictures, price etc. from online-shops, it was doable. We gave relativeness points; for example for price, if a text includes "price" it gets 2 points, if it includes "$" or "€" it gets 3 points etc. I try to say you need to do experiments on the data.
You can get forms, Javascript lines etc. as I know, and can experiment on those too.

I recommend using **Crawler4j** if you'll work with java. **Apache Nutch** is good too, you can get information about "saving raw html with Nutch" from my questions in my profile, but it's a very big project and I don't think it's worth dealing with all that stuff, for your situation.

Comment: I have no issue with crawling..I am already using a self-developed one. However, the idea of relativeness is definitely charming and yes i agree that i need to experiment. Thank you.